# Use custom progress bar android

Tags: android, progress-bar

I'm using a library for android custom progress bar and added :

```
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

My LinearLayout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:background="#F5F5F5">
```

and i used :

```
  <com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.ArcProgress
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:id="@+id/arc_progress"
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="96dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    custom:arc_finished_color="#214193"
    custom:arc_unfinished_color="#F2EDFF"
    custom:arc_max="99"
    custom:arc_bottom_text="Дист."
    custom:arc_suffix_text="км"/>
```

but when I compile the project return error :

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #65: Error inflating class com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.DonutProgress
```

Comment: Have you tried clean build?

Comment: u add?  dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.1.0@aar'
}

Comment: yes, I cleaned my project

Comment: i'm using Eclipse. what is compile 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.1.0@aar' ????? Jar file? I added : com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.1.0.jar